# Ag Grid React Prevent row selection in cell clicked handler

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How I can prevent row selection in cell clicked handler?

Not working:

```
onCellClicked={event => {
  if ((event.event?.target as HTMLInputElement).type === 'checkbox') {
      event.event?.stopPropagation();
      event.event?.preventDefault();
      return;
  }
}}
```

I have checkbox in each row (default behavior select checkbox when row selected. I dont need this). And when I click on my own checkbox row also selected. How to prevent this?

Comment: Did you try `suppressRowClickSelection` option?

Comment: @mashi I need single row selection.

Answer (score 0):

Ag-Grid works with some predefined CSS classes as many of us, this is our starting point

A bit ugly but it works

```
  onRowSelected: (params) => {
    // we are only interested in selected rows
    if (params.node.selected) {
      // here we search for an html element with class name ag-checked, we are going to remove this class if the row is selected
      const i = params.node.rowIndex;
      const el = document.querySelectorAll(
        '[row-index="' + i + '"] div[ref="eWrapper"]'
      );

      if (el) {
        el[0].classList.remove('ag-checked');
      }
    }
  },
```

Here's the plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/3kxq4itW7F8tKZCu

Tell me if you need any modifications

Comment: I use React and here discussion about my problem: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/7348

Thanks!